# Page not found when viewing Group entities

Tags: 9, group

I'm using the Group module and I've defined an "Organization" group type.

When I create an entity of that type by going to `/group/add` and hit save, I get Page Not Found for the url `/group/1`.

If I go to the entity list view at `/admin/group` I see my group, and the title is linked to `/group/1`. Clicking on it gives me Page Not Found.

`/group/1/edit` works, as do other urls like `group/1/delete`, but group/1 404s.

What am I missing here and how can I debug this? `/group/{group}` seems to be the canonical link for the Group entity as defined in `group/src/Entity/Group.php`. I'm logged in as admin.

Answer (score 0):

Tracked this down to a route collision with another entity in our codebase that was using the same route.

Debugged by adding devel_debug calls to RouteProvider.php